# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type WC_Order_Refund as array in

Tags: woocommerce

I added this code below to add prices including VAT in the admin order page.

It work well but I tried to refund an order today and I got this error:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type WC_Order_Refund as array in

How can I exclude this new price from the refund process ?

This custom price should not be submitted once I click on refund

```
//Add price inc VAT column on admin order page
function action_woocommerce_admin_order_item_values( $null, $item, $absint ) {
    $val = ($item['type'] == 'line_item' || $item['type'] == 'shipping') ? $item['total'] + $item['total_tax'] : '&nbsp;';
    $valdecimal = wc_format_decimal( $val, $dp='', $trim_zeros );
    ?>
    <td class="item_fcost" data-sort-value="<?php echo $val; ?>">
        <div class="view" style="font-weight: bold; text-align: right; padding-right: 10px;">
            <?php if ($val>0) echo '$'; echo $valdecimal;?>
        </div>
    </td>
    <?php
};
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_item_values', 'action_woocommerce_admin_order_item_values', 10, 3 );


function action_woocommerce_admin_order_item_headers( $order ) {
    echo '<th class="item_fcost sortable" data-sort="float" style="text-align: right;">Price inc VAT</th>';
};
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_item_headers', 'action_woocommerce_admin_order_item_headers', 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can quit early if the incoming $item variable is a WC_Order_Refund object.

```
if ( 'WC_Order_Refund' == gettype( $item ) ) {
    return;
}
```

Comment: It dosent't work, i am still getting this error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type WC_Order_Refund as array in /nas/content/staging/.../wp-content/themes/dt-boutique/functions.php:882 Stack trace:
#0 /nas/content/staging/.../wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(286): action_woocommerce_admin_order_item_values(NULL, Object(WC_Order_Refund), 68729)

Comment: I think that you put the code too late in the function but I have changed the $val line to use WooCommerce API functions instead of directly accessing the array elements: `$val = ('line_item' == $item->get_type() || 'shipping' == $item->get_type() ) ? $item->get_total() + $item->get_total_tax() : '&nbsp;';`

Comment: You don't need to call wc_format_decimal() with the $dp or $trim_zeros parameters. Just leave them out.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the updated code that does not generate any errors:

```
//Add price inc VAT column on admin order page
function action_woocommerce_admin_order_item_values( $null, $item, $absint ) {
  $val = ('line_item' == $item->get_type() || 'shipping' == $item->get_type() ) ? $item->get_total() + $item->get_total_tax() : '&nbsp;';
  $valdecimal = wc_format_decimal( $val );
  ?>
  <td class="item_fcost" data-sort-value="<?php echo $val; ?>">
    <div class="view" style="font-weight: bold; text-align: right; padding-right: 10px;">
      <?php if ($val>0) echo '$'; echo $valdecimal;?>
    </div>
  </td>
  <?php
};
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_item_values', 'action_woocommerce_admin_order_item_values', 10, 3 );


function action_woocommerce_admin_order_item_headers( $order ) {
  echo '<th class="item_fcost sortable" data-sort="float" style="text-align: right;">Price inc VAT</th>';
};
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_item_headers', 'action_woocommerce_admin_order_item_headers', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Great I don't see the error anymore. But the price is wrong. I need to display order subtotal instead of the total. I want to display the Original Price without the discounts. I tried to replace $item->get_total() by $item->get_subtotal(), but it dosen't work... Can I replace this by  $item['subtotal']

Comment: Please provide more information. Is the price incorrect for a single item or when multiple of the same item are purchased? Is the item on sale? Please give an example of the numbers you see and the numbers you expect to see.